# Android - Update textview depending on position clicked in RecyclerView

Tags: android, textview, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

Currently I have a RecyclerView, that opens `Activity2`/`activity2.xml`. `activity2.xml` has a textview.

MY QUESTION IS: How can I set the text in `activity2.xml` depending on what item was clicked in my recyclerview? I also want to set a image but that can wait for now.

I'm using a `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` that implements a `View.OnClickListener`.
Here is my `RecyclerView.Adapter`

RecyclerPracticeAdapter.java

```
public class RecyclerPracticeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {

Context c;
ArrayList<Category> category;

public RecyclerPracticeAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Category> category) {
    this.c = c;
    this.category = category;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.model, null);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(v);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.nameTxt.setText(category.get(position).getName());
    holder.img.setImageResource(category.get(position).getImage());

    //Listners
    //THIS IS WHERE YOU CAN CHOOSE TO OPEN A ACTIVITY WHEN USER CLICK ON A CARDVIEW!!
    holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View v, int pos) {
           switch (pos) {
                case 0:
                  // Open New Activity......
                  // THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO CHANGE TEXT activity2.xml
                  Intent intent=new Intent(v.getContext(),Activity2.class);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);

                    break;
                case 1:
                  Intent intent=new Intent(v.getContext(),Activity2.class);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);

                    break;


            }

        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return category.size();
}
}
```

activity2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Update Text"
        android:id="@+id/txt_update"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

EDIT:::

MyViewHolder:

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements  View.OnClickListener {

public ImageView img;
public TextView nameTxt;
ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    nameTxt= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameTxt);
    img= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ppImage);

    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void  setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener ic){

    this.itemClickListener=ic;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    this.itemClickListener.onItemClick(v,getLayoutPosition());
}
}
```

Category:

```
public class Category {

private int name;
private int image;



public Category(int name, int image) {
    this.name = name;
    this.image = image;


}


public int getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(int name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(int image) {
    this.image = image;
}
}
```

Comment: you can pass data in intent

Comment: What text do you need to pass? Is it the position of the clicked item? Tell more about that, I ll help to pass the data!

Comment: OBX The text will be an explanation of the "button" that was clicked. Let me use a example, lets say my recycleView has an Item of "Tennis" then I want to explain the rules of tennis in the next activity, but I want to use the same activity for each item clicked in the RecyclerView

Comment: You can go with Deepak goyal's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Pass the data with intent in onClick of item.

```
Intent intent=new Intent(v.getContext(),Activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("YOUR_KEY", category.get(pos).getName());  
v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

2.Get the data in your `Activity2`.

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if(bundle!=null){
  String text = bundle.getString("YOUR_KEY");
  if(text!=null)
    YOUR_TEXT_VIEW.setText(text);
}
```

Comment: What if I want to get the text from my `strings.xml`?

Comment: can you post your whole `RecyclerPracticeAdapter.java` class with `MyViewHolder` class

Comment: try to change in your `ViewHolder` class from `this.itemClickListener.onItemClick(v,getLayoutPosition());` to `this.itemClickListener.onItemClick(v,getAdapterPosition());`

Comment: Still nothing, textview is still blank

Comment: are you passing the intent data or not?

Comment: yes I am, the activity opens but the textview is still blank

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134764/discussion-between-deepak-goyal-and-h-brooks).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass the data

```
    Intent intent=new Intent(v.getContext(),Activity2.class);
  intent.putExtra("value",category.get(pos).getName());
  v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

and in Activity2 you need to take the value

String updatevalue=getIntent().getExtras().getString("value");
            TextView.setText(updatevalue);

Comment: Maybe you can help me, I still can't get anything to display in my `TextView`